# Setting policy values in edge://policy (Edge for Mobile)

Tags: browser-history, microsoft-edge

I'd like to specifically set the policy `SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled` to "true" - I'm hoping that means the Android Edge browser no longer will save browsing history.

How do you set the value of these policies on Android? I know how to do it through the registry on Windows, but Android?